# Linux ramdisk memory allocation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, ramdisk

My machine has a physical memory of 16 GB and I can create a ram disk of size 25 GB from this command

```
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=25G tmpfs /tmp/ram4
```

However as far as I have understood, ram disks write content to the ram. But in this case os allows me to create a ram disk of size more than my physical memory. I have couple of questions

1. When I create a ram disk, does linux actually allocate same amount of space from the ram or does it grow according to the data which comes to the disk?
2. Does ram disk only write to the memory or is there a possibility where it writes the content to swap space?

Comment: tmpfs is not the same as ramdisk.  Study http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt  and http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt  ramdisks are semi-obsolete.